# How to append a value at the end of src attribute in html string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this html in string, I want to modify the src tags such a way that I want to keep the values but append a string at the end of the attribute

HTML before modification

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LDRA Testbed Results</title>
  </head>
  <script> 
    var AddTxt = true;
    var TBpublish = true;
  </script>
  <frameset cols="206,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDERCOLOR="#DEDEEF">
     <frame src="./App_xyz_P_tbresults/App_xyz_P.lfm.htm" name="lFrame" NORESIZE>
     <frame src="htm_idx/frontpage.htm" name="rFrame" FRAMEBORDER="no">
  </frameset> 
</html>
```

HTML after modification

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>LDRA Testbed Results</title>
   </head>
   <script> 
      var AddTxt = true; 
      var TBpublish = true;
   </script>
   <frameset cols="206,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDERCOLOR="#DEDEEF">
      <frame src="./App_xyz_P_tbresults/App_xyz_P.lfm.htm:A:1" name="lFrame" NORESIZE>
      <frame src="htm_idx/frontpage.htm:A:1" name="rFrame" FRAMEBORDER="no">
    </frameset> 
</html>
```

How can I do that in Node.js

***Current code***
This is how I'm currently parsing the html code using the parser

```
var html = chunk.toString();
    var temp = html;

    html = parse(html);
    var modifiedHTML = [];
    var elementsTag = [
      "<a ",
      "<area ",
      "<base ",
      "<body ",
      "<frame ",
      "<iframe ",
      "<img ",
      "<input ",
      "<link ",
      "<script ",
      "<audio ",
      "<embed ",
      "<source ",
      "<track ",
      "<video "
    ];

    var elements = [
      "a",
      "area",
      "base",
      "body",
      "frame",
      "iframe",
      "img",
      "input",
      "link",
      "script",
      "audio",
      "embed",
      "source",
      "track",
      "video"
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < elementsTag.length; i++) {
      var count = (temp.match(new RegExp(elementsTag[i], "g")) || []).length;

      for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        var elementAttr = html.querySelector(elements[i]);

        if (elementAttr != null) {
          // console.log(elementAttr);
          if (Object.keys(elementAttr.attributes).length > 0) {
            Object.keys(elementAttr.attributes).forEach(attribute => {
              if (attribute == "src" || attribute == "href") {
                var attributeVal = elementAttr.attributes[attribute];
                // console.log(attributeVal[j]);
                attributeVal = attributeVal + `:${project_name}:${type}`;
                elementAttr.setAttribute(attribute, attributeVal);
              }
            });
          }
          modifiedHTML.push(elementAttr.outerHTML);
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(modifiedHTML);
```

Output:

```
[
[0]   '<frame src="./App_xyz_P_tbresults/App_xyz_P.lfm.htm:TEST:static_analysis_report1:TEST:static_analysis_report1" name="lFrame" NORESIZE></frame>',
[0]   '<frame src="./App_xyz_P_tbresults/App_xyz_P.lfm.htm:TEST:static_analysis_report1:TEST:static_analysis_report1:TEST:static_analysis_report1" name="lFrame" NORESIZE></frame>'
[0] ]
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser for node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: I did but when I select a frame tag it always returns me the first one so I can't change the src of tags after the first one

Comment: Post the code then...

Comment: I made the changes check it out

Answer (score 0):

It is not a trivial task to parse HTML in JavaScript. I didn't check your attempt but you should really use an existing HTML parser instead of doing your own.

You can use for example [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to achieve what you want:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

let html = `<html>
  <head>
    <title>LDRA Testbed Results</title>
  </head>
  <script> 
    var AddTxt = true;
    var TBpublish = true;
  </script>
  <frameset cols="206,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
FRAMEBORDER="no" BORDERCOLOR="#DEDEEF">
     <frame src="./App_xyz_P_tbresults/App_xyz_P.lfm.htm" name="lFrame" NORESIZE>
     <frame src="htm_idx/frontpage.htm" name="rFrame" FRAMEBORDER="no">
  </frameset> 
</html>`;

const dom = new JSDOM(html);

let frameset_children = dom.window.document.body.children;
for (let i = 0; i < frameset_children.length; i++) {
  let frame = frameset_children[i];
  frame.src = frame.src + ':A:1';
}

console.log(dom.serialize())
```

Comment: Hi, how can I modify src or href attribute for all the elements in the dom??

Comment: I suppose you can do it the same way, parsing the whole document body, with maybe some verification to identify the nodes you want to modify. You can probably use jQuery like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133813/5156280) to make it even easier for you.